# Sqlalchemy: Can't execute sync rule (in many to many relationship)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am struggling with "many to many" relationships in Sqlalchemy.
My data model:

- a chain consists of one or multiple jobs
- a job may be part of one or multiple chains

```
class Chain(Base):
    __tablename__ = "chain"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __guarded__ = ['id']
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    # .. some other fields

class JobConfig(Base):
    __tablename__ = "jobconfiguration"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __guarded__ = ['id']
    chain = relationship("Chain",  secondary='chain_job')

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    jobname = Column(String(250).evaluates_none(), nullable=False, unique=True)
    # some other fields

class ChainJob(Base):
    __tablename__ = "chain_job"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __guarded__ = ['id']
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    chain_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('chain.id'))
    job_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('jobconfiguration.id'))
```

Now when I try to create a new chain and append a new job I get an error message:

```
 chain = Chain()
 chain.name='MyFirstChain'
 job = JobConfig()
 job.jobname="PartOfChain1"
 job.chain.append(chain)
 session.add(job)
 session.add(chain)
 session.commit()
```

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedColumnError: Can't execute sync rule for
>   source column 'jobconfiguration.id'; mapper 'mapped class
>   JobConfig->jobconfiguration' does not map this column.  Try using an
>   explicit `foreign_keys` collection which does not include destination
>   column 'chain_job.job_id' (or use a viewonly=True relation).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Works for me without error.